# Error: Class Does not exist in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am having the following error

`InvalidArgumentException` in `FormBuilder.php` line 39:
Form class with name `App\Http\Controllers\App\Forms\SongForm` does not exist.

on Laravel,

**SongsController.php class**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Kris\LaravelFormBuilder\FormBuilder;

class SongsController extends BaseController {

    public function create(FormBuilder $formBuilder)
    {
        $form = $formBuilder->create(App\Forms\SongForm::class, [
            'method' => 'POST',
            'url' => route('song.store')
        ]);

        return view('song.create', compact('form'));
    }

    public function store(FormBuilder $formBuilder)
    {
        $form = $formBuilder->create(App\Forms\SongForm::class);

        if (!$form->isValid()) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($form->getErrors())->withInput();
        }

        // Do saving and other things...
    }
}
```

**SongForm.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Forms;

use Kris\LaravelFormBuilder\Form;

class SongForm extends Form
{
    public function buildForm()
    {
        $this
            ->add('name', 'text', [
                'rules' => 'required|min:5'
            ])
            ->add('lyrics', 'textarea', [
                'rules' => 'max:5000'
            ])
            ->add('publish', 'checkbox');
    }
}
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('songs/create', [
    'uses' => 'SongsController@create',
    'as' => 'song.create'
]);

Route::post('songs', [
    'uses' => 'SongsController@store',
    'as' => 'song.store'
]);
```

And I do not know where is the problem because the file exist in the project folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation of the Error**

Here:

```
$form = $formBuilder->create(App\Forms\SongForm::class, [
        'method' => 'POST',
        'url' => route('song.store')
   ]);
```

You're specifing the class name with a namespace relative to the current namespace:

```
App\Forms\SongForm::class
```

the full class name will be built relatively from the current namespace that is:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

So, the class you're passing as parameter becomes:

```
App\Http\Controllers\App\Forms\SongForm::class
```

That class doesn't exists, and so you get the error

**How to solve**

To solve, you can specify the absolute namespace. Change this:

```
App\Forms\SongForm::class
```

to this:

```
\App\Forms\SongForm::class
```

and it should work